# How to run webdriver.io tests inside a docker container without google-chrome?

Tags: docker, webdriver, chromium

I am trying to run Webdriver.io tests inside a docker container. The container is based on alpine linux.
When I run the test, it fails with the following error.

```
Error: Error: Command failed: which google-chrome

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:402:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:458:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:301:12)
```

wdio.conf.js setting is as below.

```
    capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }],
```

My docker container does not have google-chrome, but it has chromium-browser instead. Therefore, I have changed the browserName to 'chromium-browser', but the error still persists.